# Concerning Cyclic Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I am new to group theory. I have a problem but I don't really understand what it is about, so I am asking somebody to explain what is the problem (I am not really seeking for solution).

Here it is:

Let $G = C_{20}$ be THE cyclic group of order $20$. Find the number of (distinct) solutions of the equation $x^n=1$ in the group $G$, when $n=6,7,8,9$ and $10$.

First of all, is there only one cyclic group of order $20$?

It doesn't say what are the elements of the group (are they integers?), what is the operation of the group. Is there anything missing from the problem description?

Comment: In a technical sense, there are many cyclic groups of order $20$. However, any two cyclic groups of order $m$ are *isomorphic*. So "up to isomorphism" there is only one. We can take "the" cyclic group of order $20$ to be the integers $0$ to $19$, under addition modulo $20$. Alternately, you can think of it as the group of all rotations through angles that are multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{20}$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In case you are unsure, the equation $x^n =1$ means the number of elements of the group whose $n$-th power (under the given group operation) is the identity of the group.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson How can I be sure that `1` is the identity? For example under Z/20Z (addition modulo 20), the identity is `0`, am I right?

Comment: I was trying to point out that $1$ is fairly standard notation for the identity of the group, and need not be the real number $1$. Some books use $e$ to denote the identity of a group. I was also trying to point out that you have to take account of the operation in the group you are working with. So it is indeed true that (the equivalence class of) $0$ is the identity of the group $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$, but in that group $x^{n}$ should really also be written as $nx.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, you are correct. I was stupid enough to think of `1` as a real number. Anyways, I am new to abstract algebra but I dont think I will ever understand why would anybody use `1` instead of `e`. I dont think it makes any sense to use `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is well posed. The reason the question refers to *the* cyclic group of order $20$ is that all such groups are isomorphic. They are identical in terms of their group-theoretic properties.

Therefore the answer to the question will be the same whether you answer it for one cyclic group of order $20$ or any other. In this case, you can select any cyclic group of order $20$, whichever is most convenient.

In most circumstances, it will be most convenient to select the group $\mathbf{Z}/20\mathbf{Z}$. Its elements are the equivalences classes of the equivalence relation on $\mathbf{Z}$ of equivalence modulo $20$. This is probably what your question denotes by $C_{20}$.

Comment: What about `x^n=1`. Is `x` a member of the group? I also don't understand what does that equation have to do with the group(sorry for not writing it in the question).

Comment: Yes, $x$ should be an element of the group. Read about the order of the elements in a group.

Comment: The question has five parts. The first is for $n = 6$, the second for $n = 7$, etc. The first part asks you to look at the group $C_{20}$ mentioned in the question, and then say how many elements $x$ of the group satisfy the equation $x^6 = 1$. Depending on the definition of $C_{20}$ in your book, this might mean the neutral element of the group, or it might mean the element $1$ in $\mathbf{Z}/20\mathbf{Z}$, where the neutral element is $0$. I think it's more likely to be the former, but you'll need to check your book for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of representing a group. Typically, if two groups have the same properties (isomorphic) they are thought of as the same, and you can pass between the different ways of viewing the problem freely. I would say that $\mathbb Z /5$ has 3 as an element because you can think of it as 0,1,2,3,4 where values greater than 5 are removed. Or you can think of it as congruence classes. Sometimes the different ways of thinking abour a group are not as natural, but it is not unreasonable to consider the groups to still be the same. Since they have the same group properties, they are the same. It is true that there is only one cyclic group of a given order. It can be represented in different ways. So one way you can think about it is if you had integers and "moded," out. But the elements of Z/n are really the congruence classes of integers (i.e. 2,7,12 ... are in the congruence class $\overline 2$ with respect to 5). But these congruences classes it turns out act in pretty much the exact same way as integers for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the elements of a group is a divisor of the order of the order of the group. So  using this theorem you can find the number of distinct solutions of the equation $x^n=1$ for given n.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, as it was clarified above you may choose G in question to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$.

Now by Langrange's Theorem you have that the order of any element $\alpha \in G$ divides the order of G. This follows when you notice that $\langle \alpha \rangle$ is a subgroup of G. In other words $$\alpha^{|G|}=e$$

This might guide you finding the solution for $\alpha^{n}=\overline1$.